# R sqldf: Error table already in test

Tags: r, sqldf

I tested the code before and it didn't give me any errors.
Now there is an error "sqldf: table T1 already in test".
How can I fix it?

```
ret <- sqldf("SELECT T1.*, T2.score FROM T1 JOIN T2 USING(date)")
```

Comment: any chance you can print the `str` of `T1`, `T2`, and `test`?

Comment: I didn't print any of them. T1 and T2 are two tables and test is not defined.

Comment: If you want people to help you join two tables, we need to see what data is in the tables to figure out what is causing the error.

Comment: I assume you are using sqldf with MySQL or PostgreSQL.  Remove the T1 table from the test database and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to execute:

```
sqldf("drop table test.T1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a dataframe with the same name as your database table. Clear your environment and try again.